# core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: chart_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ is not a constructor

Tags: angular, chart.js, primeng

I am having this error with chartJS and primeNG:

```
ERROR TypeError: chart_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ is not a constructor
    at UIChart.initChart (primeng-chart.js:48)
    at UIChart.ngAfterViewInit (primeng-chart.js:29)
    at callHook (core.js:3038)
    at callHooks (core.js:3008)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2960)
    at refreshView (core.js:7243)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8326)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:6965)
    at refreshView (core.js:7222)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:8280)
```

in my angular.json file I have added the:
"scripts": ["node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"]

ChartJS version:     "chart.js": "^3.0.2",
PrimeNG :    "primeng": "^11.3.2",
Angular CLI v :     "@angular/cli": "~10.0.1",

Answer (score 41, accepted):

High probability primeng still only works with v2 of chart.js since v3 just released this month and had some breaking changes.

Downgrading chart.js to version 2.9.4 should resolve your issue

Comment: it works with 2.9.4, but it does cause a warning about commonJS and optimizatiton bailouts. `node_modules\primeng\__ivy_ngcc__\fesm2015\primeng-chart.js depends on 'chart.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.`

Comment: npm i chart.js@2.9.4

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made my day!

Comment: Thanks. I was going bananas with this problem.

Comment: Thanks!!!! Was hard finding this fix. Did not know about p-chart with the latest chartjs versions.

Comment: For info : Charts.js 3.3.2 works with primeng 13.3.2. It need some config modification.

Comment: Hey @cocorico, can you explain, what type of config modification need to implement?Thx!

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/getting-started/v3-migration.html

Comment: You need to check your primeng version, and check the version of chart.js it is compatible with. Each version of PrimeNg is compatible with a version of chart.js.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
    import chart from 'chart.js'
```

To:

```
    import {chart} from 'chart.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by updating chart.js to 4.4.0 with latest version of ng2-charts

Answer (score -1):

Cahnge

```
import Chart from 'chart.js'
```

into

```
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js'; 
import 'chartjs-adapter-moment'; // or another adapter to avoid moment
Chart.register(...registerables);
```

from [here](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/695).

Comment: That doesn&#39;t solve the issue, he is using a lib that internally is using chart.js so you can&#39;t change it, it has to be changed in the lib itself, also might just use the `import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'` since that will save you a line of code and is more readable